# How can I locate an index given the following constraints?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, pseudocode

> Given an array of n integers A[0…n−1], such that ∀i,0≤i≤n, we have that |A[i]−A[i+1]|≤1, and if A[0]=x, A[n−1]=y, we have that x<y. Locate the index j such that A[j]=z, for a given value of z, x≤ z ≤y

I dont understand the problem. I've been stuck on it for 4 days. Any idea of how to approach it with binary search, exponential search or interpolation search recursively? We are given an element z find the index j such that a [j] = z (a j) am i right?.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Scolytus: he's looking for `j`. Duh.

Comment: Really? ;) You can always just iterate over the whole array, but I guess that't not what he wants... So I would be happy for a bit more information...

Comment: that´s the only info the Teacher give us :(

Answer (score 3):

This:

> | A[i]−A[i+1] | ≤ 1

means that each element in your array will be *at most* one different(-ve or +ve). It then follows that the *closest* index that can contain **z** from the current is `|A[cur] - z|` spaces away.

So, what you do is start with `j=0`, and figure it out for each step. Jump that many spaces, and check again. Eventually you'll find z or reach the end.

```
public static int findZ(int[] a, int z){
    int j = 0;
    while(j < a.length){
        if(a[j] == z)
            return j
        j += Math.abs(a[j] - z);        
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This isn't a binary or exponential search, and it's not recursive, but it's simple and gets the job done. It works as a one-sided interpolation search. See below for the two-way method. You can turn it into a recursive function, but that should be straightforward and I'll leave that to you.

It runs in O(n), where your worst case performance is going to be on something like `{0,0,0,0,1}`, where it can only jump one step, and turns into a straight linear search.

Best case will be ordered, distinct members like `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`, where it will only perform one jump.

---

### Edit:

In the interests of making this more "interpolation search-like", let's move both the upper and lower bounds at the same time. The same logic applies for both ends:

```
public static int findZ(int[] a, int z){
    int j = 0;
    int k = a.length - 1;
    while(j <= k){
        if(a[j] == z)
            return j
        if(a[k] == z)
            return k;
        j += Math.abs(a[j] - z);
        k -= Math.abs(a[k] - z);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It still ends up as O(n) overall worse case, but [this is normal for an interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search#Performance).

Now your worst case is more like `{0,0,0,1,0,0,0}`, and your best is like `{0,1,2,3,2,1,0}`.

Comment: You asume that the array is ordered - it is not.

Comment: No, this doesn't assume that. Even if it's not, each element can only be `[-1, 0, 1]` different from the one before it, so it doesn't matter if it's ordered.

Comment: And nice examples - thumbs up ;)

Comment: Nice but i need to use binary, exponential or interpolation search. I dont reeally get how to use them.

Comment: + 1 for `j += Math.abs(a[j] - z);`

Comment: Thanks!...nice aproach you are really helping me :)